# MySqL Select statement not working

Tags: phpmyadmin

Hello guys can someone help me,
I create a two table and one of the table contains a foreign key, i have been trying to select the row that contains data in the table but instead MYSQL is give me only the column without the data or the row, to be specific both table contains one row
example of what i was trying to do in mysql is

**SELECT CourseName FROM course WHERE CourseName='Information Technology'**

i was also trying to search for a course that contains the same name on the database, so as to notify the user that the course already already exist

Comment: Can you provide the table structure and some sample data?

Comment: Thank you guys for replying to the message, well I'm glad to say I finally figure out the problem and the most funny thing is that when I inserted the data into the table I added space unknowing and so it lead to me having problem fetching back the data using the WHERE Clause, it was when I inserted another data that I discover the problem. Thank you guys.